# blank gap when adding view inside UIViewController

Tags: c, mkmapview

I just ran into a problem where when I'm adding a new view to my `UIViewController` there is a small gap on the top. (Appears to be the height of the status bar)

I use `pushViewController` to show this view, like this:

```
MapViewController *map = [[[MapViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:map animated:YES];
```

In my `MapViewController` I just create a `MKMapView` with the same frame as the view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:_mapView];
}
```

But it turns out to be like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm still missing something here ...

Comment: Please edit the tags to include the correct language. What you've shown isn't C.

Comment: @tinman I'm sorry, I thought Objective-C was part of the C language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

The frame of a UIView is in the co-ordinate system of the superview.

The bounds of a UIView, on the other hand, is in the co-ordinate system of the view itself.

In this case, the frame of self.view will be taking into account the status bar (as that's how it sits on the screen) - hence the status bar sized offset at the top.